# Is it possible to train a collared dove for "rock climbing"?

Tags: birds

Blue tits can do it: climbing and clinging on various structures, also upside-down, seems to be easy for this kind of birds.

https://ww2.rspb.org.uk/community/wildlife/homesforwildlife/m/hfwwildlife/35888.aspx

Also I have seen sparrows that could climb/cling (also upside-down) for a short moment on something. However, I have never seen that a collared dove "rock climbed" on something. Is this because a collared dove has more weight than a blue tit or have blue tits special forms of the feet?

Could it be possible that someone who owns a collared dove can train it to climb upside-down (rock climbers say sometimes "climbing on a overhang or roof")?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about biology in the terms of SE Biology.

Comment: If this gets closed as off topic, you could try a new question on worldbuilding SE or get this question migrated by one of the admins.